# How to convert Thunkable sql commands to Google Apps Script and link directly to a Fusion Table

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, archive, google-fusion-tables

I have succeeded using Thunkable to archive old data in a Fusion Table. I would like this to be done in the background of the app using Google Apps Script.

The Thunkable Blocks with SQL is as follows:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT ROWID FROM TableID WHERE Duration<= Clock.Now
SET GLOBAL RESULTS to List from CSV Table text (Result from Query1)
```

For each number from 2 to length of list by 1 DO Query 2

**Query 2:**

```
UPDATE TableID SET Availability='uNAVAILABLE' WHERE ROWID='list item 2 from result from Query 1'
```

Remove list item 2

**Query 3:**

```
DELETE FROM TableID WHERE Availability='Unavailable'
```

How can I convert this to Google Apps Script and link it to a Fusion Table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#ftAPI),

> A quick way to try out the API is to type the command or query directly into your browser's toolbar. You can adjust the URL as you change your query or data needs and you'll get immediate feedback. You can only do this with tables that are exportable and either public or unlisted, and you need to include your API key.

Here's a sample that runs a query to select all rows in a given table,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT * FROM 1KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4&key={your API key}
```

So, to implement this using Google Apps Script, try using [`Class UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

> Fetch resources and communicate with other hosts over the Internet. This service allows scripts to communicate with other applications or access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. A script can use the URL Fetch service to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive responses.

You may want to check this sample Google Apps script and fusion table query in this [GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/4642936) for additional insights.

```
function readFacName(fac, city){
  // public fusion table
  // https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1tL67aacGcCyMfAg9PUo_-gp4qm74GDtFiCMtFg
  var select = "select FACNAME from 1tL67aacGcCyMfAg9PUo_-gp4qm74GDtFiCMtFg ";
  var where = "where FAC_ZIP5 = '" + fac + "' AND FAC_CITY = '" + city +"'";
  var query = encodeURIComponent(select + where);
  var url = "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=" + query;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {method: "get"});
  return response.getContentText();
}
function fTable() {
  Logger.log(readFacName("94609","OAKLAND"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I will try what you suggest.